# SSAS MDX Query with Grouped Value

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I created Calculation Member which one shows a percentage ratio transactions amount to concrete institution.

```
 Case When IsEmpty ( [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] ) 
 Then Null
 Else ROUND((( [Klient].[Instytucja].[Klient].CurrentMember,
   [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] ) 
  /
  ( Root    ( [Klient] ), [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] )) *100, 2 )
 End
```

The result of my query looks like:

[image]

**Query: How to change MDX query to shows percentage usage for all institutions (except for "Brak instytucji") grouped in one rows (I mean one row with 13,05 value)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things I'd recommend

- not use `CASE` - general rul-of-thumb is that `IIF` is quicker.
- for readability I prefer the `DIVIDE` function.
- rather than Root why not just use the ALL member?

Code would now be something like this:

```
 IIF(
   [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] = 0 
  , NULL
  , ROUND(
      100 * 
      DIVIDE(
        ( [Klient].[Instytucja].[Klient].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] ) 
      , ( [Klient].[Instytucja].[All], [Measures].[Zlicz transakcje] )
      )
      , 2 
    )
```

You can create an aggregated member that excludes Brak instytucji:

```
AGGREGATE(
  EXCEPT(
     [Klient].[Instytucja].[Klient].MEMBERS
    ,[Klient].[Instytucja].[Klient].[Brak instytucji]
  )
)
```

)

Comment: Where should i add this Aggregate function ? In my calculation member in expression field i added only your IIF statement and it returns null values.